# Determine if the current thread is the only thread in the process

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading

We are using a library which needs its initialization code run in the *single* and *only* thread. The plan is to run it from the main thread. How can one check — to ensure our assumption about being the only thread holds as app evolves — that the main (current) thread is the only thread in the app at the moment?

Our app is C/C++ on Linux. I saw answers to a question "How to count a number of thread in a process" suggesting to look at `/proc`. I didn't find if there is a library/system call to obtain a number of threads.

**Update**. I don't want to run code once or from one thread I want to be able to check there are no more threads except the main one. This is my WHAT. The question is: HOW can I do this?

There is no way to run init at the start of `main()`. There are other things that has to be checked, set, initialized before we can init library.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253728/discussion-on-question-by-ivan-onys-determine-if-the-current-thread-is-the-only); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

My solution relies on the command **ps -o nlwp= <pid>**. This directly outputs the number of used threads although with a few whitespace characters at the beginning.

The -o specifies a user defined format, which says "get the number of lightweight processes (nlwp), aka threads", together with the process id of the current process, this command can be executed and the contents that it prints, be parsed to obtain the thread number.

Normally the command using that option would display information column-wise for every process using the specified keywords (e.g. our nlwp) as the header of a column, but using "=" we can set it to null, thus removing the header all together and leaving only the desired information. For more details https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html:

This code is completely written in c, but most of the library calls wouldn't change anyway, if it would be written in a more c++ like style. I tested this code for my Ubuntu 20.04 distro, which uses the bash shell. Problems could arise if another shell is used or the ps command is at another location, but its very unlikely.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//counts the threads run by the process including the main thread, 0 is regarded as a sign of an error
int getThreadCount() {
    int res = 0;

    //executing the bash command ps -o nlwp= <PID>, where -o specifies the output format with the number of light weight processes\nlwp (aka threads) and opening a file descriptor to the output of the cmd
    char cmd[32];
    sprintf(cmd, "/usr/bin/ps -o nlwp= %d", (int)getpid());
    FILE* fd = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to chech thread count (Could not open File descriptor)");
        return 0;
    }

    //read the single outputed line and parse the number in it, if no line is present or the number couldn't be parsed (output of strtol is 0) it returns with error msg
    char* line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read = getline(&line, &len, fd);
    
    //close opened file descriptor
    pclose(fd);

    if (read == -1) {
        perror("Failed to check thread count");
    }else{
        res = strtol(line, NULL, 10);
        if (res == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Failed to check thread count -> Could not parse command output\n");
        }
    }
    
    //if the line is not null, the malloced char* from getline must be freed by the caller
    if (line) {
        free(line);
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use    pthread_is_multithreaded_np()
it returns number of threads - 1